# Only parse arrays with certain hashes using Hash#select and/or Array#select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, json, hash

How does one use [Hash#select](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-select) and/or [Array#select](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-select) to only parse the `products` arrays that include `{ "name": "sale", "value": "true" }`?

Live app: http://runnable.com/U-eWKpORZ5A644gK/array-hash-select-for-ruby-on-rails (see `main_controller.rb`)

```
require 'hashie'

response = JSON.parse(@json_text)
mashie = Hashie::Mash.new(response)

@products = []
mashie.products.each do |product|
  product.extend Hashie::Extensions::DeepFetch

  product.name = product.deep_fetch(:name)

  @products << product
end
@products
```

Answer (score 4):

Using [select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-select)

```
myarr = [{ "name" => "sale", "value" => "true" }, { "name" => "test", "value" => "true"}]
myarr.select { |h| h["name"] == "sale" && h["value"] == "true" }
=> [{"name"=>"sale", "value"=>"true"}]
```

In your case, you would have a Hash (after parsing the JSON) that looks like this:

```
response = {"productHeader" => {"totalHits" => 32090}, "products" => [{ "name" => "sale", "value" => "true" }, { "name" => "test", "value" => "true"}]}
```

Then, you could just have this code:

```
response = JSON.parse(@json_text)

response["products"].select { |h| h["name"] == "sale" && h["value"] == "true" }.each do |filtered_response|
  # Do whatever you want with the filtered product
end
```

Comment: So do I combine this with `deep_fetch` or something since these values are deeply nested within `products`? Also, how do I then iterate only over the `products` arrays where this is true?

Comment: I don't think you need any ``deep_fetch``. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for coming through, but there might be a misunderstanding. I don't want to alter the `products` array itself. I just want to include only the `products` arrays that include `sale: true`. All the other `products` arrays with `sale: false` should be skipped.

Comment: You are not altering the array. You are just iterating over the ones that satisfy the condition, and skipping the other ones. If you wanted to alter the array, you could use ``select!``

Comment: Also, 1) how to better organize for multiple conditions, ie. `sale: true` as well as `sizes: Onesize`?, 2) note that the current example seems to break `Hashie::Mash` and `Hashie::Extensions::DeepFetch` which are needed to make the code look beautiful.

Comment: @MarkBoulder I would suggest asking another question for your new requirements.

Answer (score 1):

This can work even with `mashie`.

```
@products = response['products'].select do |e|
  e.is_a? Hash \
  and (f = e['fields']).is_a? Array \
  and f.any? do |g|
    g.is_a? Hash \
    and g['name'] == 'sale' \
    and g['value'] == 'true'
  end
end
```

Or try

```
@products = response['products'].select do |e|
  e.is_a? Hash \
  and (f = e['fields']).is_a? Array \
  and f.any? do |g|
    g.is_a? Hash \
    and g['name'] == 'sale' \
    and g['value'] == 'true'
  end
end.map{ |e| Hashie::Mash.new(e) }
```

Comment: Wow! Pretty slick! Any idea why it gives `undefined method 'name'` though? http://runnable.com/U-eWKpORZ5A644gK/array-hash-select-for-ruby-on-rails

Comment: @MarkBoulder It doesn't call any method called `name`. You sure you didn't change something?

Comment: Also why is there any doubt that x.is_a? Hash or y.is_a? Array?

Comment: Did you change `g['name']` to `g.name`?

Comment: Didn't change anything no, just pasted it straight into `main_controller.rb`. Please see that live app.

Comment: @MarkBoulder Try using it without Hashie.

Comment: I can't access anything there.

Comment: But that would break my entire setup.

Comment: Why can't you access it? Are you on an old version of IE, or is your IP blocked?

Comment: Perhaps you can add a `.map` to convert each element of resulting array to `Hashie::Mash`: `.map{ |e| Hashie::Mash.new(e) }`.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is getting a little too complex. By the way a friend just shared this with me: http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/

Comment: Yes the `and` operator there is used with those concepts in mind. You should just at least try the other version.